# PHP + OAuth + Google: getting 'Length required' instead of acess token

Tags: php, oauth

I'm trying to add login with Google in my app. After a user is redirect to google and returned back (with `code`) I need to get access token:

```
        $url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
        $content = "code={$code}&client_id={$params['appid']}&client_secret={$params['secret']}&" .
            "redirect_uri=$return_url&grant_type=authorization_code";

        $opts = array(
            'http'=>array(
                'method'=>'POST',
                'header'=>'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n' .
                    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($content)
            )
        );

        $cont = stream_context_create($opts);

        $response = file_get_contents($url + '?' + $content, false, $cont);
```

last line throws warning `[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 411 Length Required`. Still, as you can see I put `Content-Length` header into request. Can somebody tell me what is done wrong?

Thank you in advance!